# Is "Converting to.dfs argument to keyval with a NULL key" usually a fatal warning for failed map tasks with RHadoop?

Tags: mapreduce, rhadoop

I have written several RHadoop programs that work even though they return warnings such as:

```
Converting to.dfs argument to keyval with a NULL key
```

when inputting data with to.dfs.

However, some programs fail fatally with no warnings other than

```
Converting to.dfs argument to keyval with a NULL key
```

followed by

```
ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1.
```

Is the NULL key warning normally associated with failed Map tasks?

I know the standard advice is to look at stderr, but the stderr for the failed job is empty!  Zero lines, zero characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the

> Converting to.dfs argument to keyval with a NULL key

Is an usual warning, and it doesn't make the job fail.

Did you try fetching your data stored with the to.dfs command using a from.dfs command to see if it worked ? If it does, the problem probably lies eslewhere.

Comment: Yes, I get the NULL warning even for the jobs that work correctly.  But I have a lot of jobs that fail, so I was wondering whether the NULL had anything to do with it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i think this issue is of streaming ,i used this line in my R terminal when this problem come it may help you
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME='/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce')
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD='/usr/bin/hadoop')
Sys.setenv( HADOOP_STREAMING='/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.1.jar')

streaming may be differ by your jar file .like /usr/lib/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.2.jar is my jar...you can check by your path.

Comment: Lately I have been using:      `HADOOP_CMD=/home/user/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop
HADOOP_STREAMING=/home/user/hadoop-1.2.1/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar`                     Thanks for your mention of the HADOOP_HOME variable.